# NSCalendarIdentifierRepublicOfChina vs NSCalendarIdentifierChinese?

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I wonder what is the different of `NSCalendarIdentifierRepublicOfChina` (`NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar`) and `NSCalendarIdentifierChinese` (`NSChineseCalendar`) but can't find any information from Apple Developer website.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NSLocale Calendar Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Calendar_Keys):

> **NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar**
>   Identifier for the Republic of China
>   (Taiwan) calendar.
>
> A Chinese calendar can be created, and you can do calendrical
>   calculations with it, but you should not use it for formatting as the
>   necessary underlying functionality is not working correctly yet.
>
> Available in OS X v10.6 and later.
>   Deprecated in OS X v10.10.

and

> **NSChineseCalendar**
>   Identifier for the Chinese calendar.
>
> Available in OS X v10.4 and later.
>   Deprecated in OS X v10.10.

So

- `NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar` (which has been deprecated in favor of
  `NSCalendarIdentifierRepublicOfChina`) is for the calendar used in Taiwan.
  As I understand it, this is the [Minguo calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar) and  differs from the Gregorian calendar 
  by a difference of 1911 in the years.
- `NSChineseCalendar` (which has been deprecated in favor of `NSCalendarIdentifierChinese`) is for the traditional Chinese calendar.

The following code prints the current date (January 10, 2015 in the Gregorian calendar)
in both those calendars:

```
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.dateStyle = .FullStyle

let rocCal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierRepublicOfChina)
fmt.calendar = rocCal
println(fmt.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
// Saturday, January 10, 104 Minguo

let chineseCal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierChinese)
fmt.calendar = chineseCal
println(fmt.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
// Saturday, Month11 20, 2014(jia-wu)
```

The latter is the 20th day in the 11th month in the year of the horse (Jia Wu)